# ios schedule local notification after a delay with repeats

Tags: ios, swift

I need some help with scheduling local notification after a some delay that is repeating every 5 minutes. I'm using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger) to achieve repeats with every 5 minutes. But I didn't manage to find the way to delay this.

I can't use `dispatchAsyncAfter` because app can enter into background.

What I want to achieve is following: When user accept some event (tap on button). I want to have a reminder for him to finish the action. So i have scheduled one notification after 30 seconds, then next after 1 min and then each notification after every 5 minutes until he finish the action.

So basically I need to schedule one time interval local notification that starts appearing after exact 6,5 minutes when user tap on button.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much delay you want? Why you want that?

Comment: @MandeepSingh I have edited the post.